# Does External Tensor of Vector Bundles Preserve Zero Divisors

Tags: tensor-products, vector-bundles, k-theory

Here $X$ is a CW complex.  Suppose I have two vector bundles $V_1 \to X$ and $V_2 \to X$ such that $V_1 \otimes V_2 = 0$ in $K(X)$.  Is it then true that $V_1 \boxtimes V_2 \to X \times X = 0$ in $K(X^2)$?  My issue is that I am having a hard time thinking about $p_1^*(V_1) \otimes p_2^*(V_2)$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the two projections $X \times X \to X$.  Is there a nice description or way of thinking about it?  Thanks.

Comment: @Ruben No, this is simply complex topological K-theory.  I have edited that into the question.